# How to use WifiManager in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I'm creating an app for Android that turns off WiFi automatically. The question: How can I use the WifiManager in Xamarin Forms ? In MainActivity.cs or somewhere else ?I could not find any good examples on the internet. Thank you

Comment: to use an Android specific API from a shared Forms project, use DependencyService

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you could use the `DependencyService`.

For more details of the `DependencyService`, you could refer to the sample i done before.
[How to launch Android Settings app to your app's settings with Xamarin.Essentials Launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232523/how-to-launch-android-settings-app-to-your-apps-settings-with-xamarin-essential)

Some usage of this need to request for the runtime permission, the code sample in the link below would be helpful for the runtime permission in Xamarin.forms. [Xamarin - Requesting camera permissions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771557/xamarin-requesting-camera-permissions-in-webview)